# How compute the minimum value of a polynomial in a specific range using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a polynomial (e.g., x^3 - 3x^2 + 4) and I want to compute its minimum value in a range (e.g., between [-1,1]) using Python. I thought it would be easy using NumPy and/or similar libraries, however, I wasn't able to find the solution using Google.

Can I compute the minimum value for a polynomial fraction (e.g., (x^2 -1)/(x+3)) in a specific range using Python?

Comment: You might be looking for an optimization method of some sort. Maybe this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) from `scipy.optimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fun(x):
    return x**3 - 3*x**2 + 4

fit = minimize(fun, x0=10)
print(fit.x)
```

Output:

```
[2.00000006]
```

If you want to set specific bounds, you need to use one of the `methods` that can support it (see `methods` in linked doc page for details).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fun(x):
    return x**3 - 3*x**2 + 4

fit = minimize(fun, x0=1, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=((1,3),))
print(fit.x)
```

Output:

```
[1.99999989]
```

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a direct way to similarly find the maximum of a negative quadratic equation. From [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) I can't see a direct way. I could apply np.polyder(quad_eq) and get the value when the slope is 0, then do something like np.polyval(quad_eq, x=slope is 0). But I think there should be a better way to do that. Any comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about fractions of polynomials, you can use `numpy.polynomial`:

```
def poly_min(poly, x_low, x_high):
    # get local minima and maxima
    x_minmax = p.deriv().roots()

    # ignore the ones out of the range
    in_range = True
    if x_low is not None:
        in_range &= x_low <= x_minmax
    if x_high is not None:
        in_range &= x_minmax < x_high
    x_minmax = x_minmax[in_range]

    # append start and end points, if needed
    x_candidates = (x_minmax,)
    if x_low is not None:
        x_candidates = (x_low,) + x_candidates
    if x_high is not None:
        x_candidates = x_candidates + (x_high,)

    # find the lowest of all possible candidates
    x_candidates = np.concatenate(x_candidates)
    return p(x_candidates).min()

from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial
p = Polynomial([4, 1, -3])  # 4 + x^3 - 3x^2
poly_min(p, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend arrange function from numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def function(x):
    return x**3 - 3*x**2 + 4

def search_min(set, end, freq):
    section = np.arange(set, end, freq)
    arr = []
    for i in section:
        arr.append(function(i))

    ## This is check mid-process
    ## If this is verified you can delete this sentence
    for j in arr:
        print(j) 
    print()
    ###################################################

    return min(arr)

print('result : ',end='')
print(search_min(-1, 1, 0.1))
```

Output:

```
## mid-process
0.0
0.8409999999999997
1.5679999999999996
2.187
2.7039999999999997
3.1249999999999996
3.4559999999999995
3.703
3.872
3.969
4.0
3.971
3.8880000000000003
3.757
3.5840000000000005
3.375000000000001
3.136000000000001
2.8730000000000007
2.592000000000001
2.2990000000000017

0.0 ## result val
```