# How to find the maximum of the polynomial fit of this Python array?

Tags: python

I have max nine points of a function as the following array in Python:

```
array([0.04625943, 0.04646331, 0.04636401, 0.04636489, 0.04651253,
       0.0462647 , 0.04549576, 0.04484105, 0.04463366], dtype=float32)
```

I use numpy library and need to polyfit(2nd order) this array and find the maximum of that polyfit.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array

Comment: I dont want the max point of the array, but the max point of the 2nd order polyfit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471058/how-compute-the-minimum-value-of-a-polynomial-in-a-specific-range-using-python

Answer (score 1):

In order to fit a polynomial, you need arrays of x and y values. Since your data consists of a single array, I am not sure how you use it with `np.polyfit`.

Assuming though that you have two arrays `x` and `y`, then `np.polyfit(x, y, 2)` will return an array of coefficients `[a, b, c]` of a second degree polynomial. If this polynomial has the maximum value (i.e. if `a` is a negative number) this maximal value will be attained at the point `x0 = -b/(2*a)`. Thus, you just need to compute `x0` and then evaluate the polynomial at this value.

Comment: This is a good answer, although perhaps you could point out that if the vertex is the min then the max will occur at one of the two endpoints (of whatever interval they are interested in), which is also easy to detect.

Comment: @JohnColeman I understood that the OP was asking for the absolute maximum of the function over the whole real line. If the range of arguments is bounded, then one also needs to consider the case when the vertex gives the maximum, but it is located outside the range. In which case the maximum will be still at one of the endpoints.

Comment: @bb I calculate x0 but how do you find y max of the polyfit after that?

Comment: @GNZ Plug it into the polynomial: `y = a*x0**2 + b*x0 + c`.